# How do I add playback controls to a SWF file embeded in HTML?

Tags: html, flash

What am I missing here because my video doesn't have any controls?  Is there a special parameter I need or do I need to encode the SWF file in a special way?  I just used a MPEG to SWF converter provided by Blaze Media Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  I was thinking this was much easier than it is.  In order to get playback controls, you needs to either use some boilerplate Flash code to wrap your Flash movie or you need to script it out in ActionScript.  Basially, there is no toggle or anything to just turn controls on for a SWF movie.  You'll want to look into some sort of the Flash editor/IDE to build controls into a .fla file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/).

> Flowplayer is an Open Source video player for your website.
>
> For site owners, developers, hobbyists, businesses and programmers.